# English Proficiency, Reviewer Status

Tags: discussion

How does one become a "reviewer" (the review option in the top bar of the ELL page) without being certified as a proficient English speaker?

Comment: Reviewing is more about enforcing community guidelines than it is about providing expertise. One need not be a proficient English speaker to help flag spam, welcome new participants, or vote to close off-topic questions.

Comment: I agree with choster.  But if you ever feel you can't review something properly, regardless of whether it has to do with your language proficiency, please use the "SKIP" button.

Comment: Even native English speakers occasionally make use of the "skip" button. If you are an experienced user of ELL, you are qualified to help with most of the review tasks, and if you make a mistake, other members of the community will help fix it.

Comment: The same way reviewers on Mathematics.SE can become reviewers without being certified mathematicians – or the reviewers on Physics.SE can become reviewers without being certified physicians ;^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 350 reputation you have access to the first posts and late answers queues only, and close/reopen votes at 500 reputation. All users with more than 1000 reputation (during the beta phase of the site) have access to all review queues. No certification is required.

See [Privileges](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: It's only 350 rep to access the review queues (or at least some of them). 2000 gives you moderator tools access.